# 'Simple' Reservation System

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, forms

So I'm building a website where I present a list of locations people can read about and visit. Fairly simple you would say. But besides these locations, there are activities you can do at these locations, or near these locations. So I will create 2 CPT. One for locations and one for activities. The when creating an activity you can select a location where this activity will be at.

But now come the issue/challenge. I need to be able to let the user make a reservation for these activities. Not for all, but for some. Next to that, I need to be able to set certain activities/reservations to paid activities/reservations.

I think I will need to use a form for this but maybe I'm wrong. This form could be added to activities that need a reservation (still fairly simple I think), but I also need to be able to let a user select a certain time he or she wants to participate (predefined per activity). So there needs to be some dynamic data in it. Next to that, I need to be able to activate a price and payment system if an activity is a paid one.

So I thought about it quite a lot, and my WordPress development is quite ok, but I'm not good to add building custom plugins, etc. Is there someone who can point me in the right direction on this? Help would be widely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea for two custom post types is a good start, but you may wish to consider using [taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/) for the activities and the custom post type for the location.

To determine whether the activity needs to be reserved or not could be done by using a [custom field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) and a check on the value with `get_post_meta()`.

That should be enough to get you started.